# Why is $\mathbb{Q}$ dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology, rational-numbers

I've heard this fact numerous times in the past but I've never fully understood its proof. So I'm hoping to do it right this time:

Take the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and take the subspace topology for $\mathbb{Q}$.

To prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ it suffices to show that $\mathbb{R}\subseteq\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.

The closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ can be written as $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid \text{ if } x\in (a,b) \text{ then }(a,b) \cap \mathbb{Q} \neq \emptyset\}$

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and let $(a,b)$ be an arbitrary open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ containing $x$. It suffices to show that there exist $p\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $p\in (a,b)\cap\mathbb{Q}$, or equivalently, $a<p<b$.

How can I proceed from here?

Comment: It is easier to prove this fact by using Cauchy sequence.

Comment: You might want to look up the "Archimedean property".

Comment: I am not sure whether the mentioned definition of the closure makes sense. Using continued fractions is an elegant possibility to prove that $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$. With continued fractions, every real number can be approximated arbitary close by rational numbers, and this exactly what we need.

Comment: So basically given any $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that (without loss of generality) $a<b$, we have $b-a>0$. Let $\epsilon=b-a$, we have to find some $p\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $0<p<\epsilon$? This is equivalent to showing that $a<p<b$, hence completing my proof.

Comment: But this is exactly where I get stuck.

Comment: If you are not expected to refer to a specific construction of $\Bbb{R}$, I recommend the following. Can you show that the interval $(a,b)$ contains at least one terminating decimal number? That number is then rational, and you are done.  You do need to be aware of $0.999\ldots=1$ and its cousins.

Comment: Sidenote: If in your question "...such that $(a,b)\cap\mathbb Q\neq\varnothing$..." is replaced by: "...such that $p\in(a,b)\cap\mathbb Q$..." then it looks better.

Comment: @Peter Almost. You're not guaranteed that $a\in \Bbb Q$, so you can't know that $a+p$ is rational. However, there is at least one multiple of $p$ between $a$ and $b$, because if not, then we have, for some $n$, that $np\leq a<b\leq (n+1)p$, which contradicts $p<b-a$.

Comment: Ah I see, if $a\neq b$, then there exists some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $N$'th decimal is the smallest one such that $\forall n\leq N$, the n'th decimals of $a$ and $b$ are equal.

Comment: @Arthur I noticed my flaw and already deleted the post, nevertheless thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: "I've heard this fact numerous times in the past but I've never fully understood its proof." You must have also seen the sets ${\bf R}$ and ${\bf Q}$ more numerous times. Without truly knowing how real numbers are *defined*, it is fairy impossible to understanding/appreciate a proof  of density of ${\bf Q}$ in ${\bf R}$.

Comment: Why not, actually?

Answer (score 8):

There is some confusion here. You don't need to consider the subspace topology on $\mathbb Q$. You only need to see $\mathbb Q$ as a *subset* of $\mathbb R$. And $\mathbb R\subset\overline{\mathbb Q}$ looks weird; here, the whole universe is $\mathbb R$ and therefore what you want to prove is that $\mathbb R=\overline{\mathbb Q}$.

Now, if $a,b\in\mathbb R$ with $a<b$, just consider the sequence $\left(2^{-n}\left\lfloor2^{n-1}(a+b)\right\rfloor\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, which is a sequence of rational numbers smaller than or equal to $\frac{a+b}2$ which converges to $\frac{a+b}2$. Therefore, if $n$ is big enough, $2^{-n}\left\lfloor2^{n-1}(a+b)\right\rfloor\in(a,b)$.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the problem is to prove that for every $a,b\in\mathbb R$ with $a<b,$ there exists $p\in\mathbb Q$ such that $a<p<b.$

The set $\mathbb N = \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ cannot have an upper bound $\mathbb R,$ since then it would have a smallest upper bound $m\in\mathbb R,$ so that $m-1$ is not an upper bound. That would imply $m-1< n$ for some $n\in\mathbb N,$ so that $m<n+1\in\mathbb N,$ so that $m$ is not an upper bound of $\mathbb N.$

Thus for some $n\in\mathbb N$ we have $n > \dfrac 1 {b-a}.$

Consequently $0<\dfrac 1 n< b-a.$

Thus some member of $\left\{ \dfrac 0 n, \pm \dfrac 1 n, \pm\dfrac 2 n, \pm\dfrac 3 n, \ldots \right\}$ is in the interval $(a,b).$

Answer (score 2):

It's true by construction, really. What are the reals?
We can construct them as the metric completion of the rationals (using equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences), or as the order completion of the rationals, using Dedekind cuts. These turn out to give homeomorphic/isomorphic results, but in both cases $\mathbb{Q}$ being dense in $\mathbb{R}$ is true by construction.